# Stream app logs from folder to stdout while app running within docker

Tags: linux, logging, docker

I have a trouble with one thing:

1. My container runs with command `/opt/1C/.../crserver --some-params`
2. This app can write logs to specific folder and can not to stdout

The question is how can I stream this files like `tail -F /opt/logs/*` but keep my container process the same?

Comment: Do you know what the files are called the process writes to?
It is possible to use symlinks like this: `ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/foo/bar.log`

Comment: @mgansler, no, I'm not sure I can symlink it because for every hour this app creates new file. Like `/opt/logs/pid_1111/14_00.log` `/opt/logs/pid_1111/15_00.log` and after restart it can have another pid. So directly symlinking is not a way. I'm wondering if I run tail in background can it still print to stdout?

Comment: You could try redirecting the output of `tail` (or `tee`) to `/dev/stdout`

Comment: @mgansler how command for container will look like? `tail -F /opt/logs/* &; /opt/1C...` ?

Comment: With logs changing every hour, you may be stuck with using a volume mount to make the logs available outside of the container, unless you want to run a second process in your container to watch the directory for changes and output any new file or appended lines it sees.

Comment: So you can change the `CMD` instruction? I misunderstood that statement.
Well in that case you might want to put the `/opt/1c...` into the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction and have `tail -F ...` as the `CMD`.

Comment: @mgansler, if I'll put `/opt/1C/...` into the `ENTRYPOINT` will container be stopped and restarted if process `/opt/1C/...` will crash/stop?

Comment: @BMitch, yeah, the question is how to run two processes so docker will monitor one and second will redirect output from file to stdout.

Comment: Well, if the process crashes it doesn't matter if it was `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` (if each instruction is exclusive). But you can have Docker automatically restart the container when it stops (crashes)